# Does Javascript pass array to function by reference or value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

As my understand, Javascript pass object by reference, and a array also a object but when I create a array of integer then passing it to a function as below code:

```
function testFunc(outTestArray) {
  var aiTemp = [1,2,3,4];

  /*Using slice(0) to clone array */
  outTestArray = aiTemp.slice(0);
}

var aiTest = Array.apply(null, Array(4)).map(Number.prototype.valueOf, 0);
testFunc(aiTest);

console.log(aiTest.toString()); // aiTest still [0,0,0,0]
```

I also know that the slice(0) function just return a shallow copy of array, but in case the array is only a array of integer. So my question is **why the data of aiTest is not modified?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language

Comment: Duplicate. Short answer: Javascript is always pass by value, EXCEPT for arrays/objects.

Comment: JavaScript is always by-value (copy). Though, with objects, the value is a reference (reference-by-value). [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language) What you're expecting is a pointer, where `outTestArray` refers back to `aiTest`, which JavaScript doesn't have.

Comment: I thinks the problem is at slice(0) function. Because if in the function testFunc() i modify as follows: outTestArray[0] = 1; outTestArray[1] = 2;... then pass aiTest to this function, aiTest will be changed.

Comment: @TrungNguyen The issue is the `=`. By assigning `outTestArray`, you modify its value. But, `aiTest` still refers to the original array. The reason `outTestArray[1] = 2` behaves differently is because that modifies the array itself rather than modifying either variable.

Answer (score 2):

Function arguments are like new variable assignments, it's not like references or pointers in C. It's more something like this:

```js
function testFunc(...args) {
  var outTestArray = args[0];
  var aiTemp = [1,2,3,4];

  /*Using slice(0) to clone array */
  outTestArray = aiTemp.slice(0);
}
...
```

As you can see, in the code above you are cloning the array and assigning it the variable `outTestArray` scoped within the function, which is not accessible outside of it.

You could use a closure to achieve what you want:

```
var outerArray;
function testFunc(array) {
  var aiTemp = [1,2,3,4];
  outerArray= aiTemp.slice(0);
}
```

or even better, just return a new array:

```
function getArray() {
  return [1,2,3,4];
}

var aiTest = getArray();
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is that your concept of a shallow copy is wrong.

A shallow copy copies the contents of the array, but does not copy the things referred to by array members.

If your array was an array of references to objects, a shallow copy would copy the references, so your new array would point to the same underlying objects.

But this array is ints. The ints themselves get copied by a shallow copy.

Comment: As you say "The ints themselves get copied by a shallow copy." Yes I know this. But it is not related to why aiTest is not changed after out of function?

Comment: The array is passed by _copy of reference_. testFunc's outTestArray is a reference to the underlying array. Your aiTemp assignment sets that _reference_ to point to the new array [1,2,3,4]. Which you then copy for some reason. You're not modifying the array behind the reference, you're modifying the _reference itself_

Comment: To be clear, you could modify the underlying array by doing something that mutates it, like `outTestArray[0] = 1`. That would modify the first value of your  `aiTest`.

Comment: So: Assignment modifies references. Objects are passed by copying reference. But you can still mutate objects by calling functions on them that update their state, or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `testFunc` gets a reference to the original array which is copied into argument `outTestArray`. In the body of the function you are making `outTestArray` point to a different array. If you want to change the original array, then you could say

```
outTestArray.splice(0, outTestArray.length, ...aiTemp)
```

Note that spread operator is being used for `aiTemp`.